# How to communicate that an item can no longer be deleted

Tags: usability, web-app, design-patterns

**Scenario:** Imagine a kanban system and some tickets in it (Like Jira, Trello, etc.)

The user can add various information to a ticket, such as assignment, description, checklists, etc.

There is a time slot input where the user can add the hours they've worked on that ticket. As soon as the user adds the time slot, they will not be able to delete this ticket anymore.

**My question is:** Do I just not show the Delete option anymore? But then the user might start to look for it, and thinks there's a bug if they can't find it. Or, do I leave the Delete option, and the user gets a pop-up warning with an OK Button?

I'm not sure if I need to try to avoid warnings/alerts that they cannot fix - on the other hand, hiding an option which is usually available is also not very user friendly. Any advice?

Comment: Why user can't delete the ticket? Is it a restriction set by backend, for example relations in the database can't be broken?

Comment: @locationunknown Yes, as soon as they have put in a timeslot - they are not allowed to delete the ticket because that time will be considered for the billing part.

Comment: Is there another workflow for the user to be able to control their billing, to perhaps remove items from the invoice? My concern would be that a user doesn't have an avenue for fixing a mistake. It seems like simply adding a value in the timeslot is actually quite impactful, and forces the user down a path that has to end with the item on the invoice, when there are many ways that doing so could have been a mistake (e.g. added hours to the wrong task, felt their effort was actually better described by a different task, another user already updated the hours for the billed effort, etc).

Comment: @maxathousand The user could delete the timeslot (various timeslots) so it would be empty again = enabling the delete option.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way for the user to have some control over what gets sent off to billing. There are many ways they could have made a mistake on their hours (e.g. added hours to the wrong task, felt their effort was actually better described by a different task, another user already updated the hours for the billed effort, etc.), so **the user should have tools/workflows available to them in the app that empower them to ensure their hours billed are accurate**.

If we agree on this first point, then deleting a ticket that has timeslot data associated to it should also be supported, but explain the impact of doing so.

[image: Confirmation modal that explains that deleting the ticket will also remove the billable hours from the invoice]

In the mockup above, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button would be disabled until the checkbox is checked as a way to require acknowledgement before proceeding.

You may decide that it works better for your use case that this action is restricted to users with elevated permissions. In that case, the delete should be disabled with a message nearby that concisely explains the situation. For example, "*This ticket can only be deleted by an advanced user because it has billable hours*" or similar.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll take this into my next review and double check whether all users are able to delete or just the admin/boss. I do feel that a dialog with the warning needs to be displayed.